# Create a new 'Job ID' based on item ID in Sharepoint lists

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I'm trying to create a unique ID for each item added to Sharepoint, but I want it to extend from IDs in our existing system eg: 1533009428

Sharepoint lists cant auto-increment from a selected value, so I wanted to make a new column "Job ID" to hold the new Job ID.

I was hoping to use Microsoft Flow to update an item after it is created, and add 1600000000 to the item ID to create the Job ID, eg: 1600000002

Sharepoint > When an item is created > Update Item > Job ID = 1600000000 + ID

However, I can't figure out how to get the item ID in the Expression - is this even possible?  How else might I go about this?

Comment: Are you saying the `ID` field does not appear as an option in the Dynamic Content tab when working in Flow?

Comment: Yes.  ID is only available in the Dynamic Content/Expression window when focused on the ID field, not any of the other fields (eg: Job ID or Title)

Comment: If you use the ID to set an Initialize Variable, are you able to reference that in your expression?

Answer (score 0):

Simply copy the ID expression from the ID Field and paste to the JOB ID Field. Select ID ctrl+c, ctrl+v into JobID field [Create Unique ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNSUM.png)